# Kendo Validator always says multi-select is invalid

Tags: javascript, kendo-multiselect, kendo-validator

I have a multiselect that is dynamically created and appended to a template with the following bit of code:

```
                   if(fieldMap[i].required == true){
                        extraString = '<div class="k-edit-label" style="margin-top: -6px;"><label for="'+fieldMap[i].fieldName+'Input">'+fieldMap[i].fieldLabel+'*</label>'+helpText+'</div>\n<div data-container-for="'+fieldMap[i].fieldName+'Input" class="k-edit-field" id="'+fieldMap[i].fieldName+'Container">\n';
                        dynamicComponent = '\t<input class="multiselect-binder" id="'+fieldMap[i].fieldName+'Input" name="'+fieldMap[i].fieldName.toLowerCase()+'" data-auto-close="false" data-role="multiselect" data-bind="value:'+fieldMap[i].fieldName.toLowerCase()+'" required data-required-msg="Please Select Valid '+fieldMap[i].fieldLabel+'" data-source="[';
                        //dynamicComponent = '\t<select id="'+fieldMap[i].fieldName+'Input" data-role="dropdownlist" data-bind="value:'+fieldMap[i].fieldName.toLowerCase()+'" required data-required-msg="Please Select Valid '+fieldMap[i].fieldLabel+'">';
                    } else{
                        extraString = '<div class="k-edit-label" style="margin-top: -6px;"><label for="'+fieldMap[i].fieldName+'Input">'+fieldMap[i].fieldLabel+'</label>'+helpText+'</div>\n<div data-container-for="'+fieldMap[i].fieldName+'Input" class="k-edit-field" id="'+fieldMap[i].fieldName+'Container">\n';
                        dynamicComponent = '\t<input class="multiselect-binder" id="'+fieldMap[i].fieldName+'Input" data-auto-close="false" data-role="multiselect" data-bind="value:'+fieldMap[i].fieldName.toLowerCase()+'" data-source="[';
                        //dynamicComponent = '\t<select id="'+fieldMap[i].fieldName+'Input" data-role="dropdownlist" data-bind="value:'+fieldMap[i].fieldName.toLowerCase()+'">';
                    }
                    optString = '';
                    for(var k = 0; k < fieldMap[i].picklistVals.length; k++){
                        if(k == 0){
                           optString += '\''+fieldMap[i].picklistVals[k]+'\'';   
                        }
                        else{
                            optString += ',\''+fieldMap[i].picklistVals[k]+'\'';   
                        }
                    }
                    //Close the input component as well as the container div
                    dynamicComponent += optString + ']"/>\n<span class="k-invalid-msg" data-for="'+fieldMap[i].fieldName.toLowerCase()+'"></span></div>\n\n';
```

I run a validator.validate() on save button click to determine if information should be saved or not, which is dependent on if the multi-select input is required.

This pops up the invalid tooltip message when nothing is selected just fine. The issue is, however, that it will be marked invalid even if a selection is made. I am wondering if anyone has any solutions for how to get a validator to work correctly with the multiselect. Just hiding the pop ups is not really what I am after, as the validate() function will still fail even if the pop up is hidden, and I need the validate() function to pass.

Comment: Your problem is very peculiar and the code seems a bit complicated. It would be great if you can have a simpler version or a fiddle to get resolution.

Comment: http://dojo.telerik.com/uyAnEr/17 that dojo shows the issue with the multiselect. It is curious... If you change the multiselect declaration in the template from input to select, it works... As an input, though, the value of the element is not updated with a selection while the widget is. And the validator uses element.val() (element value, not widget value) to check for validation. This may be a bug on their end?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best, but here is what I got.

```
function Save(){
    $("#divTenureContainer .k-invalid").removeClass("k-invalid");

    var tenureChecked = $("#chkTenure").prop('checked');
    var tenureValid = Configuration_Tenure_Validator.validate();  
}

Configuration_ValidateInput = (input) => {
    var validationType = $(input).data("validation");
    var required = $(input).prop("required") || $(input).hasClass("js-required");
    if (!required) return true;

    if (validationType) {
        if (validationType === "stars") {
            return $(input).val() > "0";
        }

        if (validationType === "hashtags") {
            return ($(input).data("kendoMultiSelect").value().length > 0);
        }

        if (validationType === "required-text") {
            return $(input).val() >= "";
        }
    }

    return true;
}

var Configuration_ValidationRules = { rules: { Configuration_ValidateInput }, validationSummary: false };

var Configuration_Tenure_Validator = $("#divTenureContainer").kendoValidator(Configuration_ValidationRules).data("kendoValidator");
```